# Securing Clipboard Memory

Tags: memory, sensitive-data-exposure, clipboard, exposure

Sometimes sensitive data is copied from/to processes and external devices like (long)passwords, usernames and so forth , but also often people don't get this always in mind and forget to clean that type of memory (it is actually RAM) with the risk that another person extract this information by reading from it.

How can one make sure the data is erased as soon as he/she has the data already used for some task and thus cannot be found somewhere in the memory once the task is done?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure this"? Do you just not want it to get saved on disk? Do you want to erase it from memory as soon as it's no longer in use?

Comment: +forest i want erase it if its not longer in use, is there a method?

Comment: That's harder to accomplish, and probably requires modifying the clipboard's source code. Why are you afraid of data remaining in RAM in the clipboard's memory, though?

Comment: @forest Possibly because it's especially easy to access? Installing a (good) keylogger requires at least _some_ kernel-level access on that machine. You can slurp clipboards with one instance of extremely minor phishing, and then a malicious ad. It's not unreasonable to want to secure it; it's just virtually impossible, short of using a non-system-default clipboard, at least.

Comment: @NicHartley It's not easy to access a process' address space without high permissions. And if you have a keylogger installed, it doesn't matter how long clipboard contents stay in memory.

Comment: @forest Please reread what I wrote. Your comment is a non-sequitur.

Comment: @NicHartley I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, then. You said that clipboard memory is easy to access. I said that it is not.

Comment: @forest I talked about the clipboard. You talked about process memory. Accessing the clipboard is [one JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read), which can be run from inside a browser sandbox with no escalations or escapes. And, yes, if you had a keylogger it would be irrelevant; keyloggers were used as a point of contrast: Difficult to install for extremely high rewards. Compared to stealing clipboard data, which is pitifully easy and, if the data isn't secured _somehow_ (the thrust of this question), possibly equally high-reward.

Comment: @user34639 There aren't any (for Windows anyways, not sure about other operating systems) hooks for when data is pasted from the clipboard, so besides having some application that just clears it after _x_ seconds or having a button that clears it (or just copying a space or something) there's not much you can do.

Comment: @NicHartley The function you linked to is only available in the latest version of firefox and also requires explicit permission from the user. IIRC, browsers actually make it quite difficult to automatically paste clipboard contents into a browser without explicit user permission, because otherwise it would open up the exact weakness you are concerned about.  In other words, I believe you are mistaken.

Comment: So to agree with what @forest said, I believe modern OSs do quite a lot to protect the memory where they store clipboard contents, although this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: @ConorMancone Yes, it requires permissions; that's why I mentioned phishing. Phishing is when you set up a website to trick a user into giving you something. Sometimes it's a password; in this case it's clipboard permissions. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing). I also only picked the easiest-to-use function; [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) also exists, as do [many other methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+clipboard+text+in+browser).

Comment: @ConorMancone I apologize if that came off as condescending -- in retrospect, it kind of reads like that. I'm trying to explain for someone who hasn't spent quite a while looking specifically at browser-based attacks like this, and I'm not sure what knowledge you already have, so I'm just explaining _everything_ and hoping for the best.

Comment: @NicHartley Sorry, but I'm a long way from convinced.  You've referenced a Firefox-only API that requires explicit permissions and an IE-only API that requires user interaction.  Yes, those could be circumvented with phishing or some other social engineering attack, but I don't think that qualifies as "especially easy to access".  As I originally mentioned, browser vendors are well aware of the potential damage a user can do with easy access to the clipboard, which is why it is designed to be hard.  Then again it feels like we're just quibbling over what "easy to access" really means...

Comment: How do you define 'no longer in use'? Are you looking for a timed solution? Destroy-after-pasting?

Comment: +Mast Yeah something like an automatic destroy-after-pasting routine as soon the data is pasted somewhere than setting the mem address' value to null.